# Submit Form with data to and from cURL request

Tags: php, jquery, forms, curl

I'm trying to get a page that displays a form to allow a file upload which then, on submit runs a php function (curl) to upload the file to an API. But then I need an upload token from the API to come back and include itself in the form.

I'm not really sure what the best way to go about this is, and am a mere beginner with this stuff.

My code so far is as follows:
and as you can see I've tried running the php function on submit, and then jQuery to append a hidden input with a variable back from the curl response, but I have no idea if this is even possible.

Can anyone give any pointers to a potentially better way to do this?

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Zendesk Form</title>
</head>

<body>


<?php

require_once('zendesk.php');

if (isset($_POST["z_name"])) {

$upload = $_POST['z_attachment'];
$initial = curlWrap("/uploads.json?filename=license2233.txt", $upload, "POST");

?>

<script>
$("#zenform").append('<input type="hidden" name="z_token" value="<?php echo $upload_token; ?>" />').submit();
</script>

<?php } ?>



<div class="zenform">

<form id="zenForm" method="POST" action="zenconnect.php" name="zenform">

<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="z_name">

<label>Email:</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="z_requester">

<label>Subject:</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="z_subject">

<label>Change:</label>
<textarea value="" name="z_description"></textarea>

<label>Attach Files:</label>
<input type="file" name="z_attachment">

<!-- <input type="hidden" name="z_token" value="<?php echo $upload_token; ?>"> -->

<input type="submit" value="Send Changes" id="zenSubmit">

</form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rethink about using php-curl.

You have tagged jquery - so i suggest you capture your submit event on your form and control it yourself. this will prevent your page from rerendering.. some code of what i mean:

get your form data with selectors in this style

```
var request_data = {
  z_name: $('input#(id of zname input field').val(),
  z_subject: $('input#(id of zsubject input field').val(),
...
} //you havent set your id's yet

$.post("youruri", request_data, function(data, err){
  if(err){ 
    console.log(err); 
  } else {
    //do something with your received data
  }
});
```

does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your help,

I would definitely try this, although being a beginner, the API documentation only seems to cater for the curl method and I'm not sure I'd be able to re-code everything to Jquery / Ajax - I was using Jquery to try and manipulate the form based on the curl request but I'm assuming this probably isn't possible.

Sticking to curl would I just need to create more redirects instead of using jQuery maybe?

Comment: its a matter of your architecture. You want to do client stuff on the client and server stuff on the server. 1. client requests  form.php -> server accepts request and interprets form.php to html and sends the responce -> user sees the form infront of him and enters information -> user submits his information -> javascript(jQuery) validates this information and tells the user to correct errors -> user corrects errors and submits again -> javascript validates and finds no errors so it sends the form to the server -> server responds with: thanks for filling out my form;

Comment: this is the "workflow". Sending requests with javascript and catching the responce in callbacks and then dynamicly editing the DOM is a thing of user experience rather than architecture

Comment: If you want to design Apps / Webpages that users should find attractive you should definatly go with jquery